# groovy MarkupTemplateEngine : how to create 'use' element

Tags: groovy, template-engine

Trying to generate an SVG containing a 'use' element:

```
use('xlink:href':'#')
```

This conflicts with groovy's categories:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting at least 2 arguments, a category class and a Closure*

Is there a way to avoid conflicts like these (other then *yieldUnescaped* + raw markup string)?

Comment: Could you try `delegate.use('xlink:href':'#')`

Comment: delegate.use gives same error :(

Comment: Try `it.use('xlink:href':'#')`